# Why does Core Data deduct 1 from the numeric value of my days in NSDate

Tags: ios, json, core-data, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When I try to parse a date value into my core data using JSON, the date value is deducted by one day. e.g in JSON I write: "date": "14/03/13" and it stores it as 13/03/13 in my coredata. Any ideas as to why this is happening?? Below is my code

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd - MM - yy"];
    [dateFormatter setCalendar:[[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]];

    dayinfo.date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[obj objectForKey:@"date"]];
```

Comment: @JoshAreogun Do you know the time zone of the date in JSON. NSDateFormatter by default would assume your timeZone is in local. If the JSON date is in UTC and your timeZone -10:00, this can happen. While passing around date as string, its always better to include timeZone information to avoid assumptions.

Comment: Awesome, the timezone advice worked like a charm. you StackOverflow people are the best :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the TimeZone according to your local timezone for date.

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

or

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

or

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```